# Python multiprocessing is slower if more packages are imported

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I noticed that my code ran slower if I imported some packages (even if didn't use them).

*Example1:*

```
import time 
from multiprocessing import Process

def donothing(seconds):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    processes = []

    start = time.time()
    for x in range(10):
        p = Process(target=donothing,args=[1])
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)

    for p in processes:
        p.join()

    end = time.time()

    finish = time.perf_counter()
    print("Finished running after seconds : (perf_counter){0}  (sub){1}".format(finish,(end-start)))
```

*Output:*

```
Finished running after seconds : (perf_counter)0.19179975  (sub)0.15710902214050293
```

*Example2:*

I just add `import pandas` at the beginning of code, it runs much slower..

*Output:*

```
Finished running after seconds : (perf_counter)1.264330583  (sub)0.8281588554382324
```

Why does it happen, and how to avoid that?

Answer (score 1):

Each process starts a new python interpreter with it's respective import overhead.
There are several ways to start a new process depending on you OS.
Try to experiment with:

```
from multiprocessing import set_start_method
set_start_method("fork", force=True)
```

Comment: Pandas is also a really large module.